# MS Office COM add-in registry location

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, windows-registry, outlook-addin

I have some COM add-ins in Outlook/Word that I'm trying to manually configure in registry, but I am unable to locate the corresponding entries. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx, they should be located at

> (HKLM|HKCU):\Software\Microsoft\Office\application name\Addins\add-in
>   ID

or

> (HKLM|HKCU):\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\application
>   name\Addins\add-in ID

and I do see some add-ins there, but not all. Where are the remaining add-ins?

Thanks!
Yevgeniy

Answer (score 1):

If you have 32-bit MS Office on 64-bit OS then you'd want to check ..\Software\ **Wow6432Node** \Microsoft... keys also.

Comment: they're not in the Wow6432Node path either. Forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

I did find the missing addin. It was named differently than the documentation specified.

It does look like another location for addins is

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\

Comment: No, this is not the place for add-in registration. This is a place for add-in statistics collected by Outlook (performance monitoring, etc.). You can't register add-ins there.